# I am trying to "update" my array in react, so I won't get the same arrayelement again

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have created a Json file with a lot of pics of famous persons. I am importing that list and display a pic with the handleNext function. My goal now is, to get rid of that current displayed pic by deleting it from the array, so I won't get that pic again when I call the handleNext function again.

This is my code so far. I call the remove function inside the handleNext function. When i now console log the lenght of the array, it stays the same. Also the first below is a small part of the json file.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "img/pics/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "img/pics/2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "image": "img/pics/3.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "image": "img/pics/4.jpg"
    }
]



import images from "../Index.json"


function Celeb() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState(images);
  
    const handleNext = () => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      setImage(imageList[random].image);
      const unblurit = document.querySelector(".pic img");
      unblurit.classList.remove("unblur");
      unblurit.classList.add("blur");
      remove();
      
    }

    const remove = (id) => {
      const newList = imageList.filter(image => image.id !== id);
      setImageList(newList);
      console.log(imageList.length);
    }
    
  
  const handleStart = () => {
    const blurit = document.querySelector(".pic img");
    blurit.classList.toggle("unblur");
  }

  
  return (
    <div className='celeb'>
      <div className='celeb_buttons'>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
        <button className='play_button' onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
      </div>
      <div className='pic'>
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter the array, it returns a new one, and the original remains unchanged. That's why your console.log shows always the same length. You want to log the length of the newList instead:

```
const remove = (id) => {
  const newList = imageList.filter(image => image.id !== id);
  setImageList(newList);
  console.log(newList.length);
}
```

Edit: also, you're not calling the function using any id, so i won't remove anything. You need to call in your handleNext using `remove(imageList[random].id)`

Comment: The length of that array stays the same and I get specific images multiple times.

Comment: I've edited the answer, check it out

Comment: ah yea, forgot to call the remove function in handleNext properly. thanks dude